# Compile Clang with alternative sysroot

Tags: clang, llvm

I am compiling clang 11.1.0 from source and I want it to be configured to use an alternative sysroot  by default, such that when I compile a program using clang it will take the system headers and libraries from this alternative sysroot path by default.

For example suppose I have `/path/to/my/toolchain` as my sysroot.

When I configured and built gcc I used the options `--with-sysroot=/path/to/my/toolchain` and `--with-native-headers=/path/to/my/toolchain`. Now every time I compile a program with gcc it takes the system headers/libraries automatically from `/path/to/my/toolchain`.

I want to do the same with clang. The only way I could get it working so far is to have the option `-isysroot /path/to/my/toolchain` every time I compile a program. Is there a way to specify the sysroot path when compiling clang so that it becomes the default sysroot when running clang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DEFAULT_SYSROOT` cmake variable. E.g. `cmake -DDEFAULT_SYSROOT=<your_sysroot_path>`

Comment: Would it also work to set this option in a [configuration file](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#configuration-files)?